# Why command line java properties passed to hadoop are coming in as runtime arguments?

Tags: hadoop

I am using `hadoop jar a.jar com.class.Name -Dkey=value arg1 arg2`.

In the `Main` class when using args, I get the -D as arg value. Isn't Java supposed to ignore it?

Comment: Are you using windows OS?

Comment: now we are on CentOS

Comment: And you still have the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

According to hadoop commands manual:

Generic Options

The following options are supported by dfsadmin, fs, fsck, job and fetchdt.

```
Applications should implement Tool to support GenericOptions.
```

-conf   Specify an application configuration file.

-D =   Use value for given property.

-jt  or    Specify a ResourceManager. Applies only to job.